# Which one is a better approach ?

Tags: mysql, database

Consider the following case.

```
table 1: assessment
```

[image]

- It shows that studentID A1001 has took assessment_ID : E1.
- It shows that studentID A1002 has took assessment_ID : E2.
- assessment_ID : E1 has 5 questions.
- assessment_ID : E2 has 9 questions.

I need a table to store student's answer. Which one of the following is a better approach ?
[image]

Both table has "reference_ID" which acts as a foreign key that refer to assessment.id

Option A : I need to insert its question number (row) + its corresponding answer.
Option B : I need to add a new column to the table, whenever student take an assessment with higher number of questions.

Let say assessment_ID : E3 has 14 questions, then I need to add row10~row14 columns to the table.

My thought
Option A: Many records are created in this case. Option A has 14 records, while Option B has only 2 records.

Option B: Some columns are wasted because not all assessment have 9 questions.

Which one is a better solution in terms of performance, speed of execution and storage space?

Thanks.

Comment: If your column names contain numbers you are doing something terribly wrong. Option B is aweful

Comment: Option B won't scale at all...you are growing columns every time you take in new data.  This isn't even a good option in Excel.

Comment: definitely option A. you should never go horizontal with your values. What if you later get a test with 40 questions on it ? Go with A, dont forget to define proper indexes, and it will work great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version:  Option A is the better answer **most** of the time.  Here's a detailed [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) of why.

Medium version:  Option A will take up more space.  Execution speed will depend on what query you are running.

Long version: Adding a new assessment does not require any code changes under Option A.  You just define the questions and away you go.  (I would also probably add a table called "question" that contains, well, questions!)

The fly in the ointment:  the ONE query that will make Option A a pain is if you want to show answers in columns.  Because then you would have to have code that pivots the answer table.

Parting shot:  "Choose a data representation that makes the program simple."  ([Elements of Programming Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style), rule 12).  So when you are thinking about how to design your database, think of the ways in which you will use it, and pick the design that makes your code easy to write.

Comment: Thanks ! it's been very helpful for me.